# A static Java method for multi-indexing a collection

Tags: java

I have this small utility for selecting from a collection via multiple indices at one method invocation:

**MultiIndexUtils.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public final class MultiIndexUtils {

    private MultiIndexUtils() {}

    public static <T> List<T> multiIndex(Collection<T> collection,
                                         Collection<Integer> indices) {
        List<T> indexedElements = new ArrayList<>(indices.size());
        T[] array = (T[]) collection.toArray();
        indices.forEach((Integer index) -> { 
            indexedElements.add(array[index]);
        });
        return indexedElements;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> multiIndex(Collection<T> collection,
                                         Integer... indices) {
        return multiIndex(collection, Arrays.asList(indices));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
        System.out.println(multiIndex(strings, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 5, 4));
    }
}
```

## Critique request

I would like to hear anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, nice touch with `BADCAFE` :)

Then, for my two cents:

- To me it feels a bit strange using `Collection` for the element supplier type. Since we are indexing values, it would seem strange to use it on a `Set` for example, as it does not impose order.
- On a similar note, using a `Collection` for the indices parameter seems strange as well, for the same reasons. A `Set` also implies uniqueness, so no two equal indices would be passed.

Both would seem to make more sense being `List`s to me. But this is something I am just saying based on what I am feeling :)

Continuing:

- You can relax the type bound on the input parameter of the elements supplier, like so:

  ```
  public static <T> List<T> multiIndex(final Collection<? extends T> collection, ...
  ```

  Now you can pass a collection parameterized with `T` or with a subtype of `T`, which makes it more versatile.
- Seeing as you are extracting elements, you can annotate the array cast with a `SuppressWarnings`, as it is safe:

  ```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  final T[] array = (T[]) collection.toArray();
  ```
- Finally, I'd generally think twice before using `forEach` on a `Stream`, as it implies using stateful operations. Personally, I think in this case it can be more cleanely written as:

  ```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  T[] array = (T[]) collection.toArray();
  return indices.stream()
          .map(index -> array[index])
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

Comment: That is a GOODCAFE.

Comment: If the code is rewritten to use the `List` interface  instead of `Collection`, you can also ditch the array conversion and just use `List.get()`

Comment: @RobAu, good point!

Answer (score 2):

Just a note to keep in mind:

There is no rule that *utility classes* (in the sense that they provide common behavior)  have to be `static`and *not insatiable*. Thats just a misconception because classes with only static methods used to be called *utility classes* (in the sense that they have only `static` methods).

Static access to methods and class members  makes the code using it tight coupled and therefore hard to reuse, extend or otherwise maintained. It effectively blocks *dependency injection* and *polymorphism*, two of the major reasons why we use an *object oriented* language in the first place.

So when creating your classes you should not default to *uninstantiable static* classes.

Comment: Should I provide an interface + a default implementation?

Comment: @coderodde Always create only code which is actually needed. Your design should define if a *interface* is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important point was already mentioned: The elements should be contained in a `List`. The difference between a `Collection` and a `List` is exactly that: The `List` allows **indexed access**. And for a utility function that offers a "special form" of indexed access, it is reasonable that the function requires a `List`.

Think of it that way: When you call it with a `List`, you still have do the time- and memory-consuming `toArray` call, even though you already *could* use indexed access. You only "forgot" that, because you know the `List` only as a `Collection`.

More generally, you should think about what you internally need in order to properly do your work. This is the "core" method that you can implement. And in your case, you need something that you can access using indices, and the indices themself.

When you have this "core" method, you can still wrap convenience methods around it. So for example, if this is really crucial, you could even consider offering two versions of the method:

```
public static <T> List<T> multiIndex(Collection<T> collection, ...) {
    return multiIndex(new ArrayList<T>(collection), ...);
}
public static <T> List<T> multiIndex(List<T> list, ...) {
    return multiIndex(list, ...);
}
```

When you call it with a `List`, it will call the `List` version. For other collections, it will call the `Collection` version that converts the collection into a `List`. In any case, you can internally work with what you need: A `List`, which provides the necessary indexed access, that you otherwise had to quirkily allow with the `toArray` call.

---

The indices raise similar questions. If the method is **supposed** to be called like you showed it in the example, you could use `int` instead of `Integer`. If using a `Collection<Integer>` is a case that you explicitly want to cover, you have several options of how to implement your "core" method:

```
<T> List<T> multiIndex(List<? extends T> list, int ... indices)
<T> List<T> multiIndex(List<? extends T> list, Collection<Integer> indices)
<T> List<T> multiIndex(List<? extends T> list, IntStream indices)
<T> List<T> multiIndex(List<? extends T> list, Stream<Integer> indices)
```

Again, you can create wrappers in the one or the other direction. For example, you can convert the `int ...indices` array into a `Stream<Integer>` by calling

```
IntStream.of(indices).boxed()
```

or vice versa, convert the `Collection<Integer>` into an `IntStream` by calling

```
indices.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
```

---

In any case, note that the "core" method can probably be fairly trivial in the end:

```
public static <T> List<T> multiIndex(List<? extends T> list, IntStream indices) {
    return indices.mapToObj(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Another hint: Depending on your exact use cases, you could also consider to just create a *view* on the required elements of the list:

```
private static <T> List<T> multiIndexView(
    List<? extends T> list, int ... indices)
{
    return new AbstractList<T>()
    {
        @Override
        public T get(int index)
        {
            return list.get(indices[index]);
        }

        @Override
        public int size()
        {
            return indices.length;
        }
    };
}
```

Changes in the original list will then be visible in this view. (If you also implement the `set` method, also vice versa). So then you can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");

    List<String> view = multiIndexView(strings, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 5, 4);

    // Prints BADCAFE
    System.out.println(view);

    strings.set(2, "B");
    strings.set(5, "B");

    // Prints BADBABE :-)
    System.out.println(view);

}
```

If you still want a method that returns a **new** list, then you can, once more, simply wrap the call:

```
public static <T> List<T> multiIndex(List<? extends T> list, int ... indices) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(multiIndexView(list, indices));
}
```